# Laravel @push not working in create_category.blade.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Created a template folder inside views folder and in header.blade.php and added the following code

```
<ul id="sidebar">
             @stack('sidebar')
</ul>
```

And created another category.blade.php inside views folder and added the following code

```
@include('template/header')
@push('sidebar')
         <li>Sidebar first</li>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `@stack` can only be defined in an outer layout. So if you want to use `@push`, you have to use `@extends('template.header')` instead of `@include('template.header')`.

In your case I don't think it is okay to use `@extends` you probably use an other layout file.

I searched for it in the Laravel issues and I found this [Thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13809). Maybe this can clarify some things for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
This can be particularly useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child views
```

better to use @include insted @push and @stack